# unistd_64.h in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

unistd_64 as my understanding (with lots of limited) contains the system call number. When I search the file from terminal, it shows more than one results under different directories as below:

1. /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h
2. /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23/arch/sh/include/asm/unistd_64.h
3. /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/ asm/.unistd_64.h.cmd
4. /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/asm/unistd_64.h

I don't understand the difference between these files and the use of each file. And the file number 3 has .cmd, what does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing an ordinary C program that needs to know system call numbers, you should not use any of those headers.  Instead, you should use `<sys/syscall.h>`.  Your C program does not need to know the full pathname of this header; `#include <sys/syscall.h>` is all that is necessary.  However, if you want to read it, it will be found somewhere in `/usr/include`, probably either `/usr/include/sys/syscall.h` or `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/syscall.h`.

Now, I will explain the files you found:

- `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h`: This is a header file that may be used internally by `sys/syscall.h`.  You can read it, but do not include it directly in your program.  It probably defines a whole bunch of names that begin with `__NR_`.  Those names should never be used in an ordinary, "userspace" program: always use the names beginning with `SYS_` instead.
- `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23/arch/sh/include/asm/unistd_64.h` and `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/asm/unistd_64.h`: These are private kernel headers.  They exist for the sake of people trying to build kernel modules that are developed separately from the kernel proper.  It's possible that one of them is textually the same as `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64` but that is not something you should rely on.
- `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/ asm/.unistd_64.h.cmd`: This is not a header file at all, it is used by the Linux kernel's build system.

Comment: The last comment is clear for me. So, I open 3 files and make a comparison. I notice that :the system call number in 2 files /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64 and /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/asm/unistd_64.h are the same (_ASM_X86_UNISTD_64_H 1), while the system call in the last one /usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-23/arch/sh/include/asm/unistd_64.h  is different (#define __ASM_SH_UNISTD_64_H) . Can you help me with this one? What is SH stand for? what is the difference between those 2

Comment: SH is short for [SuperH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperH), which is a CPU architecture (like "x86" and "SPARC" and "MIPS" and "ARM").  The system call numbers used by Linux vary from architecture to architecture.  It appears that SH and x86 are the only two CPUs for which Linux internally uses a header named "unistd_64.h".  If you do `find /usr/src/linux-headers-* -name 'unistd*.h'` you should discover a whole bunch more.  Again, none of these headers should be used in an ordinary program; unless you are writing kernel code you don't need to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

The first file, which resides in `/usr/include` (the system include directory) is the one you would include.

The others reside in `/usr/src`, which is a source code directory that should not be referenced.

Comment: The others should be used if you're building a kernel module… might be better to say "use `<asm/unistd_64.h>`, your build environment should take care of choosing the right one".

Comment: I got your first point that is the one under /usr/include will be referred to when compiling. How about other ones? Can you explain clearer about them such as when should we used them? I think there should be reasons but I can't look up from google

Comment: To first order, you should not use _any_ header whose `#include` name is `<linux/something.h>` or `<asm/something.h>` unless you are writing code that will be part of the Linux kernel.  (There are a small handful of exceptions which you will know when you trip over them.)