# unistd_64.h in Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

Currently, I use linux kernel v5.8 on x86.

On my ubuntu machine, `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h` is old compared to `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-50-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h`.

Therefore, I cannot see the new system calls such as `openat2` that is added from linux v5.6 in the `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h`
(Ofcourse, I can see such system calls in `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-50-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h`.)

I think that `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h` is same `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-73-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h` that is previous kernel version I used.

Why was `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h` not updated?

Ref: [unistd_64.h in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468677/unistd-64-h-in-ubuntu)

Comment: The header `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h` is part of libc (glibc) library. The header `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-50-generic/arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h` is part of the Linux kernel. Updating Linux kernel doesn't imply, that your glibc will be updated automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syscalls provided by your kernel does not have to match the syscalls your C library knows about. The `openat2` was added to `glibc` by commit [`e788bea`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=e788beaf093bfafecd6b4456b984bd927c18987a) in April 2020:

> Update syscall lists for Linux 5.6.
>
> Linux 5.6 has new openat2 and pidfd_getfd syscalls. This patch adds
> them to syscall-names.list and regenerates the arch-syscall.h files.

The next `glibc` release was `2.32`, in August 2020. In Ubuntu, [`libc6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libc6&searchon=names) packages with version `>=2.32` are currently only available for `groovy` and `hirsute`:

> Package libc6
>
> - bionic-updates (libs): GNU C Library: Shared libraries
>   2.27-3ubuntu1.4: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
>   also provided by: libc6-udeb
> - focal-updates (libs): GNU C Library: Shared libraries
>   2.31-0ubuntu9.2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
>   also provided by: libc6-udeb
> - **groovy** (20.10) (libs): GNU C Library: Shared libraries
>   **2.32**-0ubuntu3: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
>   also provided by: libc6-udeb
> - **hirsute** (21.04) (libs): GNU C Library: Shared libraries
>   **2.33**-0ubuntu5: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x

But since you would not be getting much portability by requiring `glibc>=2.32` and `linux-kernel>=5.6` anyway, you could define the syscall numbers in your code (`ifndef`) and use [`syscall(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) instead.